# xamarin listview checkboxes

Tags: android-listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I added custom listview. And I added checbox in rows. I have to use ItemChecked event but I have an error->"cannot resolve symbol 'ItemChecked'"
and "cannot resolve symbol 'ItemCheckedEventArgs '"

```
 ziyaret_listesi = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.list_ziyaret_kayitlari);
 ziyaret_listesi.Adapter = new CustomAdapterZiyaretRapor(this, list_ziyaret_rapor);
 ziyaret_listesi.ItemChecked += ListView_ItemChecked;
 private void ziyaret_listesi_ItemChecked(object sender, ItemCheckedEventArgs e)
 {
     // the checked state of an item has changed
 }
```

Why cannot resolve itemchecked event in c# Xamarin?

Comment: I don't believe that ListView has an ItemChecked event.  In your example code, ziyaret_listesi is of type ListView.  Is the ItemChecked event in your custom ListView class?  If so, you'll need to cast or change the type argument in your FindViewById call.

Comment: yes ziyaret_listesi is typeof listview. ItemChecked event is not in my custom Listview class. I am trying to use "ItemCheckedEventHandler ItemChecked " but it cannot be resolve in program. Listview has Itemchecked. you  can look in https://msdn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/library/system.windows.forms.listview.itemchecked%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: That is Windows Forms ListView - it is not at all the same thing as an Android ListView.  Please see https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Widget.ListView/ for the correct class reference and https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/working_with_listviews_and_adapters/ for an introduction to Xamarin Android ListView.

Comment: Thanks for your answer